# Binomial Series Outside Brackets

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm stuck on this question regarding Binomial series and cannot get this into the form $(1+x)^n$.

Question is:
$50x(25+x)^{1/2}$

Teacher suggested expanding brackets but this breaks the laws of maths. I couldn't find a single example either in my textbook or on the internet to explain how to eliminate the $x$ term outside of brackets. Also it has to be done without a calculator, so expanding out ridiculous numbers is impossible. 
Any help would be fantastic.

Cheers

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Hint: First move the $25$ out of the brackets, so that you get $(1+??)^{1/2}$. Now you have the standard form. I guess can finish the task.

Answer (score 0):

Realised the simple answer is to apply BOMDAS. The 50x is simply taken out of the equation until the power function is solved.

50x(25+x)^1/2 becomes

=(50(25(1+x)^1/2))

= (50(5(1+x)^1/2)

Solve 5(1+x)^1/2 in binomial series then multiple the binomial answer by 50x.